# How can I align an image to the left bottom of a column using either HTML or CSS with no text at all?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm very new to HTML and I don't really have a clue about what exactly it does but I've managed to get a single decent webpage but I've got an image that just doesn't move to the left. I've got three columns and I want the image to move to the left of the left column; I've added both align and float but neither move it to the left. I'm so frustrated that I feel I'm missing something very simple.

This is the line

```
<img src="eeee" float="left" alt="eee" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
```

Comment: Use `absolute` [positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Comment: Just providing the code for the image is not very helpful.  You mention you have 3 columns and the image. Please provide an example including the 3 columns and your image. Include the CSS and the HTML please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the style of the containing element `style="float:left"`.

If your container is a `td` then set the `td` style.

```css
.some-class{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px  solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="some-class"><img src="eeee" alt="eee" style="width:100px; height:100px;border: 1px solid red;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why even mention table elements? There is no mention of them in the question.

Comment: He was talking about columns , so I guessed a table. Doesn't really matter as long as he'll set the style to the containing element

Answer (score 0):

Add in your css margin-right:auto;display:block;

```
<img src="eeee"  alt="eee" style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-right:auto;display:block;">
```